# I want to the information about my screen (if it's locked or not), Android

Tags: android, screen, locking

i'm making a program that disables your wifi when you lock your screen
but i can't find an object the holds that kind of information (wether it's locked or not)

Answer (score 2):

In most Android phones Wifi is turned off a few minutes after the screen is locked.
This setting can also be controlled by the user in `Settings->Wireless Netowrks->WiFi->Advanced`.

Anyway, if you want to tell when the screen is locked, register to receive the [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) broadcast intent.